# How Do I Get Additional Results from EnvelopesAPI.ListStatusChanges

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to practice defensive programming.  Following the advice from the documentation, I want to poll using the api passing in a value 3 minutes before the last time I polled.  Considering, I could get a ResultSetSize less than the TotalSetSize, I'd like to ask for the next set of results starting at the next result.

So, as an example, I request the following (using the REST API explorer):

```
GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/#####/envelopes?count=2&from_date=2017-01-01&from_to_status=changed HTTP/1.1
```

*(note the count = 2)*

This returns:

```
Object
resultSetSize:  "2"
totalSetSize:  "8"
startPosition:  "0"
endPosition:  "1"
nextUri:  "/accounts/#####/envelopes?start_position=2&count=2&from_date=1%2f1%2f2017+12%3a00%3a00+AM&from_to_status=changed"
previousUri:  ""
 envelopes: Array [2]
```

Ok, great, exactly as I expect.  Now, I want to get the second "page" of results.  I add a start_position of 2, right? (Since the end position is 1, I'd expect to get startPosition 2 and endPosition 3 to be returned.)

```
GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/#####/envelopes?count=2&from_date=2017-01-01&from_to_status=changed&start_position=2 HTTP/1.1
```

No dice... 400 Bad Request:

```
Object
errorCode:  "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER"
message:  "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Query parameter 'count' was not a positive integer."
```

The count parameter is a positive integer...

Please, someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.  I would like to just request as many as they can pass at a time, and if there are more, I'd like to repeat until all envelopes have been retrieved, but that "count" error is concerning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges/)

**start_position**  parameter is reserved for DocuSign use only.

Looks like pagination is not supported with the *listStatusChanges* api.

Comment: I see.  I guess I just have to not specify a count, and pray that the ResultSetSize is never less than the TotalSetSize.  Not knowing what the limit on returned envelope statuses makes this a scary proposition.

Answer (score 0):

If you call the nextUri address, what happens? You will need to prepend your base URL.

Comment: Calling the nextUri throws the error _"The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Query parameter 'count' was not a positive integer."_