# Docusign Paging Envelope JSON Data

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am integrating Docusign using REST API to download the document attachments and uploading them to Sharepoint using DocuSign [c# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/test/Recipes/CoreRecipes.cs)

I can see the `envelopes.NextUri`, but I am not sure how to page the data , 
JSON response -

```
nextUri":"/accounts/<acc-id>/envelopes?start_position=100&count=100&from_date=7%2f10%2f2016+5%3a24%3a59+AM&from_to_status=changed&to_date=8%2f14%2f2017+5%3a24%3a59+AM&status=Completed","previousUri":"","resultSetSize":"100","startPosition":"0","totalSetSize":"6709"}
```

Could you please provide me  a snippet on how to page the JSON data on nextUri parameter?.

Comment: Paging is not supported with the listStatusChanges api. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43357114/1219543)

Comment: Thanks @CodingDawg

Comment: Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [listStatusChanges](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges/) api does not support pagination.

Why do you want to implement pagination on top of the api? Why not just retrieve the entire dataset and cache it in your application.

Since you just want to download the documents and archive them to Sharepoint, you can just used the cached data and mark it as completed in your application.

---

### Retrieving partial Data

You also have an option to obtain partial data using the date ranges.

```
GET /restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes?from_date=2017-01-01&to_date=2017-02-01

GET /restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes?from_date=2017-02-01&to_date=2017-03-01
```

**Using C# SDK**

```
// set a filter for the envelopes we want returned using the fromDate and count properties
var options = new EnvelopesApi.ListStatusChangesOptions()
{
    fromDate = "6/16/2017",
    toDate = "6/30/2017"
};

// |EnvelopesApi| contains methods related to envelopes and envelope recipients
var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
var envelopes = envelopesApi.ListStatusChanges(accountId, options);
```

---

## Microsoft Flow

Also take a look at [DocuSign for Microsoft Flow](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/DocuSign-for-Microsoft-Flow-Overview). With this you can automate the task of archiving documents to Sharepoint.

Comment: well the API can give only 100 records at one time , for a 24 hr datetime ranage , thats max limit , for the next set of records , I was looking to implement it using the helpers classes in Docusign.dll

Comment: I am able to retrieve more than 100 records with the listStatusChanges API. Are you using the same API call? Can you please share your GET URL with the query parameters.

Comment: I am not using the GET URL , I am using the class from the Docusign Nuget Package

Comment: I am using this code from the Official Docusign C# client -   
// |EnvelopesApi| contains methods related to envelopes and envelope recipients
            EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
            EnvelopesInformation envelopes = envelopesApi.ListStatusChanges(accountId, options);

i am not sure if you know about this - https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/test/Recipes/CoreRecipes.cs

Comment: Instead of specifying the `ListStatusChangesOptions.count`  property. Specify `ListStatusChangesOptions.fromDate` and  `ListStatusChangesOptions.toDate`. This will retrieve all the records in the date range. I have updated my answer.

Comment: oh. what .. is it that simple.. Le me try this tomorrow and update you , Earlier I had set the count to 200 , which threw an exception.  I'll update this answer tomorrow.

Comment: Yes it works, Thank you so much. I can't believe i just overlooked this. It was right there :)